# Is there a series of $e^x$ that only contains $\sin(x)$ in the form of $e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n\cdot \sin(x)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, laurent-series

Hy i'm trying to find a series of the following kind:

$e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n\cdot \sin(x)^n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \  x\in \left(a,b \right)$

or maybe

$e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(c_n\cdot x)^n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \  x\in \left(a,b \right)$

or any other variation of the series, so that $e^x$ is only expressed in a series of $\sin(x)$ and it's powers.

**(I am aware of the fact that $\sin(x)$ is periodic, so the series can only converge on an intervall of maybe $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$)**

I have two questions:

- Do such a series exist?
- How is this subject of study called?

I know about the Fourier Series:

$e^x=\frac{e^\pi-e^{-\pi}}{\pi}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cdot \sin(n\cdot x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\cdot \cos(n\cdot x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ x\in (-\pi,\pi)$

and the Taylor Series:

$e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ x\in\mathbb{R}$

but both of them are not what i'm searching for.
I'm mainly interested if there exists any work on this subject an how it is called, so that i can read into it.

Just with a similar method to the Taylorseries and with matching up of the coefficients with the derivatives of $e^x$, i was able to produce:

$e^x\approx 1+\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(x^2)+\frac{1}{3}\sin(x^3)+\frac{1}{4!}\sin(x^4)+\frac{61}{5!}\sin(x^5)+\cdots$

which looks like:

[**Function plot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Lbf.jpg)

which looks pretty cool in my opinion :)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you can write $e^x = \sum c_n \sin^n(x) + \sum d_n \cos(x) \sin^n(x)$, but I'm not sure how to eliminate the $\cos(x)$.  The idea is to take the usual fourier expansion of $e^x$ (on some small enough interval), then use trig identities to rewrite $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ as polynomials in $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.  Then, anywhere you see a power of $\cos$ which is $2$ or more, use $\cos^2 = 1-\sin^2$.  See, e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html for the knds of identity I'm thinking about.  (I am ignoring converence issues here, so maybe it doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks :) I will try it out and post my results in an answer

Comment: In principle you can maybe write $\cos x = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\binom{1/2}{k}\sin^{2k} x$, which can be combined with Jason's comment to finish things off. But there may be convergence issues, and even if not things will get really complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it on $[0,a]$ for some $a>0$. The "trick" is to extend the function to $[-a,a]$ as an odd function, i.e. for $x<0$, define $f$ as $f(x)=-\exp(-x)$. Then it will be an odd function on $[-a,a]$, so it will only have $\sin$ terms in the Fourier series. This is called Fourier Sine Series.

Comment: That sounds super promising :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(u)=e^{\sin^{-1} u}$. Then $f(u)$ has a Taylor expansion $f(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n u^n$ at $u=0$. We therefore have

\begin{align*}
e^x&=f(\sin x)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \sin^n x
\end{align*}

which is in your first form.

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20expansion%20of%20e%5E%28arcsin%20x%29%20at%20x%3D0) to do the busy-work for us, we can see that

$$
e^x = 1 + \sin x + \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x + \frac{1}{3}\sin^3 x + \frac{5}{24}\sin^4 x + \frac{1}{5}\sin^5 x + \dots
$$

in a neighborhood of $x=0$ where $\sin^{-1} \sin x = x$ (i.e., for $x \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$).

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fliranxfum)'s a graph demonstrating this approximation.

Comment: This is what i thought about :) Thanks that solves the Problem for this one series

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes (given that you're happy for convergence to be on some subinterval of $[0, \pi]$) by appealing to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. This doesn't give you a constructive way to find the $c_n$ though.